# Prove that a neighborhood function converges to zero

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Define $D_r^x(x_0) = (x_0 - r, x_0 + r)$ - {$x_0$}. Let f: $D_r^x(x_0) \to R$. prove that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x) = 0$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to x_0}|f(x)| = 0$.

For this question, since there is a discontinuity point at $x_0$, I can only say that $\lim_{x\to x_0^-}f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to x_0^+}f(x) = 0$ How can I apply the definition of a function to prove that $\lim_{x\to x_0}|f(x)| = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=0$. Then for all $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ with $|x-x_0|<\delta\implies|f(x)-0|<\epsilon$. The implied inequality can be rewritten as $|(|f(x)|)-0|<\epsilon$ since the absolute value is idempotent ($|x|=|(|x|)|$). Hence we get the forward implication, and a similar method gives the reverse implication.

Comment: This is a general approach to prove the limit of a function. But in this question we have discontinuity at $x_0$. Can we still apply this method? Do we need to use right and left limits?

Comment: @hck007 For both implications (the "if" and the "only if"), you start off by assuming that one limit exists, and use that fact to prove that the other limit exists.  At no point do you need to invoke the continuity of the function.  Indeed, this function is not continuous at $ x_0 $ because it is not defined there, but that is not relevant.

Comment: @Jake Mirra Thanks for clarification. thus, I just need to use the definition of limit to prove the statement. I do not need to care about the continuity of the function right?